# libgdx - removing the circle outline rendered on Box2d CircleShape

Tags: java, libgdx

```
CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
circle.setRadius(1f);
...
using 
...
batch.draw(textureRegion, position.x - 1, position.y - 1, 
                            1f, 1f,
                            2, 2, 
                            1, 1, 
                            angle);
```

I use this to set the body for a Box2d collision but I get a silly circle shape around my texture in libGdx, i.e. my textured sprite (ball) has a circle over the top of it with a line running from center along the radius.

Any ideas on how to remove the overlying circle lines?

Comment: This is a cross-post with http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27066/2601. You're using the debug renderer.

Answer (score 6):

Not 100% sure, haven't used Box2d with libgdx in a while. But look if you have any `Box2DDebugRenderer` that renders the box2d world. If so, just don't call its `render()` method.

Answer (score 1):

yes, uncomment the following line.

```
debugRenderer.render(world, viewport.getCamera().combined);
```